# 500 error on cloud page - Ampscript not rendered

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I'm trying to update a field using the _Subscriberkey on CloudPage (Marketing cloud). I don't know the reason why I get an 500 error when I try to publish.

```
%%[
  var @individualID, @ObjectType, @ObjectRow, @Object, @IsConsent, @IsConsent_Status
  set @subkey = RequestParameter("_subscriberkey")
  set @ObjectType = 'Individual'  

  set @Object = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(@ObjectType, 'Consent', "Id", "=", @individualID)
  set @ObjectRow = Row(@Object, 1)
  set @IsConsent = FIELD(@ObjectRow, "Consent")

  if @IsConsent == FALSE then
    set @IsConsent_Status = "True"
  endif

]%%
```

I'm using a form to send this to a receive page.

```
<form id="from_unsubscribe" name="from_unsubscribe" action="%%=MicrositeURL(https://...../....)=%%" method="post">
```

Thanks for help!

---

This is the full code  on the first page (send page):

```
%%[
  var @individualID, @ObjectType, @ObjectRow, @Object, @IsConsent, @IsConsent_Status
  set @individualID = RequestParameter("_Subscriberkey")
  set @ObjectType = 'Individual'  

  set @Object = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(@ObjectType, 'Consent', "Id", "=", @individualID)
  set @ObjectRow = Row(@Object, 1)
  set @IsConsent = FIELD(@ObjectRow, "Consent")

  if @IsConsent == TRUE then
    set @IsConsent_Status = "False"
  endif

]%% 

<form id="from_unsubscribe" name="from_unsubscribe" action="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(https://.........com/.......))=%%" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="ObjectType" value="%%=v(@ObjectType)=%%"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="individualID" value="%%=v(@individualID)=%%"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="IsConsent_Status" value="%%=v(@IsConsent_Status)=%%">
  <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Unsubscribe">
</form>
```

And I get the data with this code (on the second page):

```
%%[
  var @individualID, @ObjectType, @resultIsConsent_Status

  set @individualID = requestparameter("individualID")
  set @ObjectType = RequestParameter("ObjectType")

  set @resultIsConsent_Status = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(@ObjectType,@individualID,"Consent", "False")

]%%
```

Comment: I'd check your MicrositeURL() value.  Should not be a URL, rather the ID of the page per https://ampscript.guide/book/micrositeurl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based off of all the previous answers and comments, I think the issue is that the subscriberKey is not being passed from the email to the first landing page.

In order to pass this information, you have 2 choices:

1. Utilize the [CloudPagesURL()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm) function
2. Manually pass the parameter (similar to an HTTPGET)

**1 CloudPagesURL()**
For CloudPagesURL(), you would need to insert the following inside of your link, instead of the raw URL: `<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL({{yourCloudPageID}}))=%%">`.  Notice that there is a [RedirectTo()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/redirectto.htm) surrounding the CloudPagesURL call - this is to ensure it gets wrapped same as all other links and allows everything to pass through correctly.  The CloudPage ID should be available in the properties section of your page.

This will then allow you to utilize your exact code as the CloudPagesURL passes all associated data that would be passed to your email into your cloud page.

**2 Manual Parameters**
Your other option is to attach the subscriberKey onto the URL to pass it as a parameter that you can then gather on the Cloud Page.  An example would be: `<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CONCAT("{{YourURL}}", "?subkey=", AttributeValue("_SubscriberKey")))=%%">`

Then on the page you would replace `set @individualID = RequestParameter("_Subscriberkey")` with `set @individualID = RequestParameter("subkey")`.

The main issue with this is that it directly and openly passes the PII of the person (subscriberkey - which most of the time it is the email address) inside the URL, leaving it open for anyone to view - which can lead to malicious activity.

If you decide to manually pass it, I would utilize some sort of encryption prior to sending via the URL and then decrypt it on the Cloud Page. See some encryption options [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/EncryptSymmetric.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If your using Cloud Pages then you should be using the Cloud Pages URL function.

[CloudPages URL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm)

Comment: Where are you defining @individualID. You seem to be directly using the variable without assigning value to it.

Comment: I'm trying this :
<form id="from_unsubscribe" name="from_unsubscribe" action="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(https://.....com/.......))=%%" method="post">

Unfortunately, I have the same error 500.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
%%[
  var @individualID, @ObjectType, @ObjectRow, @Object, @IsConsent, @IsConsent_Status
  set @individualID = RequestParameter("_subscriberkey")
  set @ObjectType = 'Individual'  

  set @Object = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(@ObjectType, 'Consent', 'Id', '=', @individualID)
  set @ObjectRow = Row(@Object, 1)
  set @IsConsent = FIELD(@ObjectRow, 'Consent')/*you can remove this line because you are retrieving only one column in the row. */

  if @IsConsent == 'FALSE' then /* you need to use quotes for comparing @isConsent value to False */
    set @IsConsent_Status = 'True'
  endif

]%%
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!
I unfortunately still have the same result.. but the code is working when I put directly the individualID like this : 

set @individualID = "1929IZUEG3GEG3GEK9"

Comment: Are you passing '_subscriberkey' in your URL? Can you post your URL here?